# Commas between adjectives

Tags: convention, article-writing

Is it correct to use these expressions without commas (as written below)?

> 1. A finite simple group.
> 2. A finitely generated abelian group.
> 3. A finitely generated torsion-free abelian group.
> 4. A finitely generated periodic infinite group.

From my experience, I can't remember ever seeing commas in any expressions of this kind (in mathematical texts). But that could be because I simply wasn't paying attention to punctuation.

I've spent some time googling for the appropriate rule, and the rule says that commas should be avoided between *cumulative* adjectives, and should be used between *coordinate* adjectives. To distinguish between the two, the following test is usually suggested: if the adjectives can be rearranged, and also the phrase doesn't look weird when "and" is placed between them, then these adjectives are coordinate.

When I try to apply the rules to cases 1-3, I feel a certain amount of doubt. In case 1 I could agree that "a simple finite group" sounds unusual. In case 2 I could also agree that "abelian group" is a very common expression, so it feels natural to place "abelian" after all other adjectives.

But what about case 4? The three modifiers seem to be more or less on equal footing. It doesn't look weird at all when they are rearranged or when "and" is tossed in: "an infinite, periodic, and finitely generated group" - looks fine to me.

So, my questions are:

1. Are examples 1-4 above correct or not? Why?
2. Is there a convention to avoid commas between adjectives in mathematical texts altogether (ignoring the general English rule)?

Thanks.

Comment: The only answer to that "possible duplicate" contains the rule that I'm already familiar with. I have cited the rule to show that I know the rule, but I'm still having doubts about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) In my opinion they look fine. Part of the issue is that only a few disciplines in writing ever have the opportunity to link together so many adjectives, and mathematics is one of them.

I could cook up some excuses why using no commas would be appropriate, but ultimately I think the better argument is that if we rigidly enforced rules that made use use lots of commas, there would simply be too many commas. In general, overuse of commas disrupts cognitive flow while reading.

2) There probably is, but I imagine it's unwritten. I've never heard or read advice about this rule. You described that in your experience you don't recall commas being used this way, and I would say the same thing. Finally, it is unlikely that the absence of commas in this particular location will draw attention. There are far more egregious writing problems that will do that.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot, this is very useful. And second, I'm afraid to ask, but what do you mean by "egregious writing problems"? Are you talking about common problems in general, or about specific problems you can see in the text of my question? If it's the latter, do tell me! Learning to write in English is why I came to math.SE in the first place, so any advice is welcome.

Comment: @DanShved Well, one thing that bugged me about an article I recently reviewed is that everything was written as a definition or proposition, and there was zero exposition. It made for a very dry, aimless paper with no motivation at all. The problem was exacerbated by the fact that out of the 40 items, fully 2/3 were definitions. So please PLEASE knit your results and definitions together with a few helpful sentences.

Comment: @DanShved Another peeve is using "if and only if" when defining a term. This topic can sometimes open a can of worms, which I don't want to go into in these comments, but needless to say the convention is not to use "iff" in definitions.

Comment: @DanShved Another mundane rule of thumb is not to overuse tropes like "obviously/clearly/easy to prove." Just think of things that have annoyed you about papers or texts you've read, and then tell yourself "don't do that!"

Comment: Thanks for the advice! For me personally, the hardest problem to avoid is the last one, because it's also annoying when the author proves every trivial detail, and I don't want to do that either. Of course, the absolute worst is when someone carefully proves all these trivialities, and then when time comes for an actual difficult result they decide that it's finally time to use "clearly" on you ))

Comment: @DanShved Sure, as with many things it's a judgement call :) Using it for truly easy things is definitely forgivable, but I have a feeling sometimes it is used to prove things that aren't actually true :)